# Perform Root Valume Swap for EC2 via the AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've recently been using the Swap root volume approach for creating a persistent Spot Instance, as described [here](https://blog.slavv.com/learning-machine-learning-on-the-cheap-persistent-aws-spot-instances-668e7294b6d8) (Approach 2).  Typically it takes 2-5 minutes for my Spot Instance to be fulfilled and the Swap to complete.  However, some days, the process never finishes (or at least I get impatient after waiting 20 minutes to an hour!).

To be clear, the Instance is created, but the Swap never happens: I can ssh into the server but my persistent files are not there.  I also can see this by going to my AWS console and noting that "spotter" (my persistent storage) has no attachment information:

[image]

As the swapping script which I'm using never gives me any errors, it's hard to see what's failing. So, I'm wondering if based on my screenshot I can just use the AWS EC2 Management Console to "manually" perform the swap, and if so, how would I accomplish this.

And, if it helps @Vorsprung,

I initiate the process by running the following script:

```
    # The config file was created in ondemand_to_spot.sh
export config_file=my.conf
cd "$(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})"

. ../$config_file || exit -1

export request_id=`../ec2spotter-launch $config_file`
echo Spot request ID: $request_id

echo Waiting for spot request to be fulfilled...
aws ec2 wait spot-instance-request-fulfilled --spot-instance-request-ids $request_id

export instance_id=`aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests --spot-instance-request-ids $request_id --query="SpotInstanceRequests[*].InstanceId" --output="text"`

echo Waiting for spot instance to start up...
aws ec2 wait instance-running --instance-ids $instance_id

echo Spot instance ID: $instance_id

echo 'Please allow the root volume swap script a few minutes to finish.'
if [ "x$ec2spotter_elastic_ip" = "x" ]
then
        # Non elastic IP
        export ip=`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $instance_id --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" --output=text`
else
        # Elastic IP
        export ip=`aws ec2 describe-addresses --allocation-ids $ec2spotter_elastic_ip --output text --query 'Addresses[0].PublicIp'`
fi

export name=fast-ai
if [ "$ec2spotter_key_name" = "aws-key-$name" ]
then    function aws-ssh-spot {
        ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws-key-$name.pem ubuntu@$ip
        }
        function aws-terminate-spot {
        aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $instance_id
        }
        echo  Jupyter Notebook -- $ip:8888
fi
```

where my.conf is:

```
# Name of root volume.
ec2spotter_volume_name=spotter
# Location (zone) of root volume. If not the same as ec2spotter_launch_zone,
# a copy will be created in ec2spotter_launch_zone.
# Can be left blank, if the same as ec2spotter_launch_zone
ec2spotter_volume_zone=us-west-2b

ec2spotter_launch_zone=us-west-2b
ec2spotter_key_name=aws-key-fast-ai
ec2spotter_instance_type=p2.xlarge
# Some instance types require a subnet to be specified:
ec2spotter_subnet=subnet-c9cba8af

ec2spotter_bid_price=0.55

# uncomment and update the value if you want an Elastic IP
# ec2spotter_elastic_ip=eipalloc-64d5890a

# Security group
ec2spotter_security_group=sg-2be79356

# The AMI to be used as the pre-boot environment. This is NOT your target system installation.
# Do Not Modify this unless you have a need for a different Kernel version from what's supplied.
# ami-6edd3078 is ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20170113
ec2spotter_preboot_image_id=ami-bc508adc
```

and the ec2spotter-launch script is:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # "Phase 1" this is the user-facing script for launching a new spot istance

    if [ "$1" = "" ]; then echo "USER ERROR: please specify a configuration file"; exit -1; fi

    cd $(dirname $0)

    . $1 || exit -1

    # New instance:
    # Desired launch zone
    LAUNCH_ZONE=$ec2spotter_launch_zone
    # Region is LAUNCH_ZONE minus the last character
    LAUNCH_REGION=$(echo $LAUNCH_ZONE | sed -e 's/.$//')
    PUB_KEY=$ec2spotter_key_name

    # Existing Volume:
    # If no volume zone
    if [ "$ec2spotter_volume_zone" = "" ]
    then # Use instance zone
            ec2spotter_volume_zone=$LAUNCH_ZONE
    fi

    # Name of volume (find it by name later)
    ROOT_VOL_NAME=$ec2spotter_volume_name
    # zone of volume (needed if different than instance zone)
    ROOT_ZONE=$ec2spotter_volume_zone
    # Region is Zone minus the last character
    ROOT_REGION=$(echo $ROOT_ZONE | sed -e 's/.$//')


    #echo "ROOT_VOL_NAME=${ROOT_VOL_NAME}; ROOT_ZONE=${ROOT_ZONE}; ROOT_REGION=${ROOT_REGION}; "
    #echo "LAUNCH_ZONE=${LAUNCH_ZONE}; LAUNCH_REGION=${LAUNCH_REGION}; PUB_KEY=${PUB_KEY}"

    AWS_ACCESS_KEY=`aws configure get aws_access_key_id`
    AWS_SECRET_KEY=`aws configure get aws_secret_access_key`

    aws ec2 describe-volumes \
            --filters Name=tag-key,Values="Name" Name=tag-value,Values="$ROOT_VOL_NAME" \
            --region ${ROOT_REGION} --output=json > volumes.tmp || exit -1

    ROOT_VOL=$(jq -r '.Volumes[0].VolumeId' volumes.tmp)
    ROOT_TYPE=$(jq -r '.Volumes[0].VolumeType' volumes.tmp)

    #echo "ROOT_TYPE=$ROOT_TYPE; ROOT_VOL=$ROOT_VOL";
    if [ "$ROOT_VOL_NAME" = "" ]
then
  echo "root volume lacks a Name tag";
  exit -1;
fi

cat >user-data.tmp <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo AWSAccessKeyId=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY > /root/.aws.creds
echo AWSSecretKey=$AWS_SECRET_KEY >> /root/.aws.creds

apt-get update
apt-get install -y jq
apt-get install -y python-pip python-setuptools
apt-get install -y git

pip install awscli

cd /root
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/slavivanov/ec2-spotter.git
echo Got spotter scripts from github.

cd ec2-spotter

echo Swapping root volume
./ec2spotter-remount-root  --force 1 --vol_name ${ROOT_VOL_NAME} --vol_region ${ROOT_REGION} --elastic_ip $ec2spotter_elastic_ip
EOF

userData=$(base64 user-data.tmp | tr -d '\n');

cat >specs.tmp <<EOF
{
  "ImageId" : "$ec2spotter_preboot_image_id",
  "InstanceType": "$ec2spotter_instance_type",
  "KeyName" : "$PUB_KEY",
  "EbsOptimized": true,
  "Placement": {
     "AvailabilityZone": "$LAUNCH_ZONE"
  },
  "BlockDeviceMappings": [
    {
      "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
      "Ebs": {
        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
        "VolumeType": "gp2",
        "VolumeSize": 128
      }
    }
  ],
  "NetworkInterfaces": [
      {
        "DeviceIndex": 0,
        "SubnetId": "${ec2spotter_subnet}",
        "Groups": [ "${ec2spotter_security_group}" ],
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true
      }
  ],
  "UserData" : "${userData}"
}
EOF

SPOT_REQUEST_ID=$(aws ec2 request-spot-instances --launch-specification file://specs.tmp --spot-price $ec2spotter_bid_price --output="text" --query="SpotInstanceRequests[*].SpotInstanceRequestId" --region ${LAUNCH_REGION})
echo $SPOT_REQUEST_ID
# Clean up
rm user-data.tmp
rm specs.tmp
rm volumes.tmp
```

Comment: I don't think you need to do this anymore with spot instances. Have you seen this new feature? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-stop-resume-workloads-on-ec2-spot-instances/

Comment: It looks like this feature can only be used "when capacity is no longer available at or below your bid price" which isn't my use case.

Comment: I went to the linked page you mention.  You need to ask this question again but with full details of the script (i think it is "start_spot.sh") that is failing.  I'm sure someone can work out a way of getting diagnostics out of the script to understand why it doesn't work, or fixing it somehow.  To manually attach a different root volume, stop the instance, detach the current root volume and attach the one you want to use instead with exactly the same parameters (usually /dev/sda1 as the mount point)

Comment: @Vorsprung I've added the code for the associated scripts.  And, yes, getting diagnostics from within the script would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Where you ware looking for the errors? @Eric

Comment: I was hoping to get an error out of one of the scripts.  However, I'm not sure whether I just need to wait a lot longer (i.e. if I don't bid enough, perhaps the root Swap is not a "priority" for AWS) or one of my scripts above is just failing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer, but it may help you to find the way to debug the issue.
As I understand, this is the part of your setup is in the `ec2spotter-launch` script responsible for volume swap:

```
...
cat >specs.tmp <<EOF
{
  "ImageId" : "$ec2spotter_preboot_image_id",
  ...
  "UserData" : "${userData}"
}
EOF

SPOT_REQUEST_ID=$(aws ec2 request-spot-instances --launch-specification file://specs.tmp --spot-price $ec2spotter_bid_price --output="text" --query="SpotInstanceRequests[*].SpotInstanceRequestId" --region ${LAUNCH_REGION})
```

The specs.tmp is used as instance launch specification: `--launc-specification file:://specs.tmp`.

And the "UserData" inside the launch specification is a script which is also generated in `es2spotter-launch`:

```
cat >user-data.tmp <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo AWSAccessKeyId=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY > /root/.aws.creds
echo AWSSecretKey=$AWS_SECRET_KEY >> /root/.aws.creds

apt-get update
...

cd /root
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/slavivanov/ec2-spotter.git
echo Got spotter scripts from github.

cd ec2-spotter

echo Swapping root volume
./ec2spotter-remount-root  --force 1 --vol_name ${ROOT_VOL_NAME} --vol_region ${ROOT_REGION} --elastic_ip $ec2spotter_elastic_ip
EOF
```

The actual work to swap the root volume is performed by the `ec2spotter-remount-root` script which is [downloaded from github](https://github.com/slavivanov/ec2-spotter/blob/master/ec2spotter-remount-root).

There are many `echo` statements in that script, so I think if you find where the output goes, you'll be able to understand what was wrong.
So when you have the issue, you'll ssh to the instance and check the log file.
The question is what file to check (and if the script output is being logged into some file).

Here is what I suggest to try:

1. Check standard logs under `/var/log` generated when the instance is starting (cloud-init.log, syslog, etc) to see if you can find the `ec2spotter-remount-root` output
2. Try to enable logging by yourself, something similar is discussed [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=149759)

I would try modifying the `user-data.tmp` part in `es2spotter-launch` this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data ) 2>&1
echo AWSAccessKeyId=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY > /root/.aws.creds
...
echo Swapping root volume
./ec2spotter-remount-root  --force 1 --vol_name ${ROOT_VOL_NAME} --vol_region ${ROOT_REGION} --elastic_ip $ec2spotter_elastic_ip
EOF
```

Here I've changed first three lines to enable logging into `/var/log/user-data.log`.

3. If 1 and 2 don't work, I would try asking script author on github. As there are lots of `echo`s in the script, the author should know where to look for that output.

Hope that helps, also you don't need to wait for the issue to appear to try this out, instead look for the script output on successful runs too.
Or, if you are able to make few test runs, then do that and make sure you can find the log with script output.

Comment: Though this isn't the complete answer, the information provided will definitely set me on a track where I can solve the issue.